# Unable to get telnet to work and test pop 995 port

Tags: cpanel, telnet, pop3

Trying to test email login issues on a cpanel server. Telnet isn't working to test port 995. Keep receiving connection closed by foreign host error. Thanks!

Telnet is installed and firewalls open. Not able to figure this out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 1):

995 is the port for POP3 with implicit TLS. Use `openssl` instead. For example:

```
openssl s_client -quiet -crlf -connect pop.gmail.com:995
```